# How to show keyboard whenever input the text box

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone-8, textbox, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm new to `Worklight` and having many troubles with it.

I'm developing an app using BingMaps. In my app, I use a Search button. When a user wants to search some location, my app show a text box, then user type an address. (When user use this button, must touch the text box one more times to show the keyboard)

But I don't know how to show the keyboard with the text box whenever a user touches the Search button.

This is my code.

```
<div id="divSearchA" style=" display:none; position:absolute; top:300px; left:90px; right:0px;height:100px; background-color:gray; opacity:0.7;"> 
    <b>Search Box: </b><input id="txtSearchA" style="width:213px" type="text">
    <br>
    <button id="btSearch" onclick="LoadSearchModule()" type="button">Search</button>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A keyboard usually comes to view when the focus is on an input field.

From your description I understand that in your case the text field is hidden, and in order to display it the end-user taps the "search" button,
So what I would try to do is: once pressing the search button, that field will get auto-focus thus the keyboard should come to view as well.

I haven't tried this yet myself so I cannot be certain:

1. Try adding the [`autofocus` HTML5 attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control%3a-the-autofocus-attribute) to your text field. See if that's suffice
2. In case 1 above will show a keyboard even when the text field is hidden, try adding it dynamically upon tapping the "search" button.